# PHP cookie impossible to read issue

Tags: php, cookies

My PHP is unable to read a cookie like this:

```
1010081-COP-9-20-20110606172032

echo $_COOKIE["SubmCookie"];
```

It just returns empty...

How is that possible?

This is the way how I set the Cookie:

```
setcookie("SubmCookie",$refNumb, time()+3600*24);
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_COOKIE)` show?

Comment: So are you doing `$_COOKIE['SumbCookie']` on a subsequent request, or on the same request?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
setcookie("SubmCookie",$refNumb, time()+3600*24,'/');
```

Comment: Oh you save my day! That was the path! You are right! Thank you so much!

Comment: when cookie aren't read 99% of time users forgot the 4th param

Comment: Good thinking, but perhaps you could add an explanation of what the `$path` parameter does.

Comment: @lone: this is not the point of the question. But if you need i can copy/paste it from php.net/setcookie